# Cluster Heat Maps Library

Tags: java, heatmap

Is there any Library in Java that has Cluster Heat Maps already implemented ?
Can I use that Library in my code to generate a cluster heat map ?
I am looking to plot cluster heat maps from gene expression data that I have.

Comment: Which one did you finally use?

Comment: I ended up using RServe to make a call to R from Java. I used the heat maps that R was generating. It sufficed the requirements of the project that I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you leverage off [Java TreeView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtreeview/) (overview [here](http://jtreeview.sourceforge.net/docs/overview.html)) ? Although it's a standalone app, I'd hope you can create a suitable library from it.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Java Treeview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtreeview/) - "An Open Source, Extensible Viewer for Microarray Data in the PCL or CDT format"

You can try sample applets online: http://jtreeview.sourceforge.net/examples/applets.html

Answer (score 0):

I used [Matthew Beckler's Java Heat Map](http://www.mbeckler.org/heatMap/) a while ago. Check it out.